# How to get total referenced memory of a variable?

Tags: dictionary, go, memory, slice

I am curious about the memory cost of `map` and `slice`, so I wrote a program to compare the sizes. I get the memory size by `unsafe.Sizeof(s)`, but obviously it is wrong, because when I change the size, the output is the same.

```
func getSlice(size int) []int {
    t := time.Now()
    s := make([]int, size*2)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        index := i << 1
        s[index] = i
        s[index+1] = i
    }
    fmt.Println("slice time cost: ", time.Since(t))
    return s
}

func getMap(size int) map[int]int {
    t := time.Now()
    m := make(map[int]int, size)
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }
    fmt.Println("map time cost: ", time.Since(t))
    return m
}

func TestMem(t *testing.T) {
    size := 1000
    s := getSlice(size)
    m := getMap(size)
    fmt.Printf("slice size: %d\n", unsafe.Sizeof(s))
    fmt.Printf("map size: %d\n", unsafe.Sizeof(m))
}
```

Comment: There is no _need_ to do this as you can calculate the space needed: Multiply cap of the slice with the size of each element. For maps it is more difficult as some interna are not accessible (e.g. hash collisions) but it is basically the same.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`unsafe.SizeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) and `reflect.Type.Size()` only return the size of the passed value without recursively traversing the data structure and adding sizes of pointed values.

The slice is relatively a simple struct: [`reflect.SliceHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader), and since we know it references a backing array, we can easily compute its size "manually", e.g.:

```
s := make([]int32, 1000)

fmt.Println("Size of []int32:", unsafe.Sizeof(s))
fmt.Println("Size of [1000]int32:", unsafe.Sizeof([1000]int32{}))
fmt.Println("Real size of s:", unsafe.Sizeof(s)+unsafe.Sizeof([1000]int32{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/r2ejk8JPx2)):

```
Size of []int32: 12
Size of [1000]int32: 4000
Real size of s: 4012
```

Maps are a lot more complex data structures, I won't go into details, but check out this question+answer: [Golang: computing the memory footprint (or byte length) of a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847549/golang-computing-the-memory-footprint-or-byte-length-of-a-map)

### Calculating size of any variable or structure (recursively)

If you want "real" numbers, you may take advantage of the testing tool of Go, which can also perform memory benchmarking. Pass the `-benchmem` argument, and inside the benchmark function allocate only whose memory you want to measure:

```
func BenchmarkSlice100(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getSlice(100) }
}
func BenchmarkSlice1000(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getSlice(1000) }
}
func BenchmarkSlice10000(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getSlice(10000) }
}
func BenchmarkMap100(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getMap(100) }
}
func BenchmarkMap1000(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getMap(1000) }
}
func BenchmarkMap10000(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { getMap(10000) }
}
```

(Remove the timing and printing calls from `getSlice()` and `getMap()` of course.)

Running with

```
go test -bench . -benchmem
```

Output is:

```
BenchmarkSlice100-4    3000000        471 ns/op        1792 B/op      1 allocs/op
BenchmarkSlice1000-4    300000       3944 ns/op       16384 B/op      1 allocs/op
BenchmarkSlice10000-4    50000      39293 ns/op      163840 B/op      1 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap100-4       200000      11651 ns/op        2843 B/op      9 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap1000-4       10000     111040 ns/op       41823 B/op     12 allocs/op
BenchmarkMap10000-4       1000    1152011 ns/op      315450 B/op    135 allocs/op
```

`B/op` values tell you how many bytes were allocated per op. `allocs/op` tells how many (distinct) memory allocations occurred per op.

On my 64-bit architecture (where the size of `int` is 8 bytes) it tells that the size of a slice having 2000 elements is roughly 16 KB (in line with 2000 * 8 bytes). A map with 1000 `int-int` pairs required approximately to allocate 42 KB.

Answer (score 17):

This incurs some marshaling overhead but I've found it's the simplest way during runtime to get the size of a value in go. For my needs the marshaling overhead wasn't a big issue so I went this route.

```golang
func getRealSizeOf(v interface{}) (int, error) {
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := gob.NewEncoder(b).Encode(v); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return b.Len(), nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way, using `unsafe.Sizeof(s)`. It's just that result will remain the same for a given type - integer, string, etc., disregarding the exact value.

> Sizeof takes an expression x of any type and returns the size in bytes of a hypothetical variable v as if v was declared via var v = x. The size does not include any memory possibly referenced by x. For instance, if x is a slice, Sizeof returns the size of the slice descriptor, not the size of the memory referenced by the slice.

Reference [here](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof).

**Update:**

You can use marshalling and then compare values representations in bytes with `Size()`. It's only matter of converting a data to a byte string.

Comment: so how can I get the real size in my situation?

Comment: This would incur the marshalling overhead. Wonder if there's a way to do it without marshalling.