# How much memory do golang maps reserve?

Tags: dictionary, go, heap-memory

Given a map allocation where the initial [space](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) is not specified, for example:

```
foo := make(map[string]int)
```

The [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) suggests that the memory allocation here is implementation dependent. So (how) can I tell how much memory my implementation is allocating to this map?

Answer (score 17):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d99fe1f40dfacfdebee22c13ed4471fd50f2cc1a/src/runtime/map.go#L303) of Go's map type, you will see, that a map consists of a header (type `hmap`) and an array of buckets (type `bmap`). When you create a new map and don't specify the initial space (`hint`), only one bucket is created.

A header consists of several fields:

1 * `int`,
  2 * `uint8`,
  1 * `uint16`,
  1 * `uint32`,
  2 * `unsafe.Pointer`,
  1 * `uintptr`.

Size of the types `int`, `uintptr`, and `unsafe.Pointer` equals the size of a word (8 bytes on 64 bit machines).

A bucket consists of an array of 8 * `uint8`.

This gives a total of 40 + 8 = 48 bytes (64 bit architecture)

Answer (score 15):

You may use the Go testing tool to measure size of arbitrary complex data structures. This is detailed in this answer: [How to get variable memory size of variable in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-variable-memory-size-of-variable-in-golang/44258164#44258164)

To measure the size of a map created by `make(map[string]int)`, use the following benchmark function:

```
var x map[string]int

func BenchmarkEmptyMap(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = make(map[string]int)
    }
}
```

Executing with

```
go test -bench . -benchmem
```

The result is:

```
BenchmarkEmptyMap-4     20000000   110 ns/op      48 B/op    1 allocs/op
```

So the answer is on my 64-bit architecture: **48 bytes**.

As hinted, size may depend on architecture. Also size may depend on the initial capacity you may pass to [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make), as you can see in this example:

```
func BenchmarkEmptyMapCap100(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        x = make(map[string]int, 100)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BenchmarkEmptyMapCap100-4   1000000    1783 ns/op   4176 B/op    3 allocs/op
```

A map of type `map[string]int` with an initial capacity of 100 now requires 4176 bytes (on 64-bit arch).

The default initial capacity is around 7 if not specified explicitly.

Comment: If I allocate a map of size 1000, will the memory usage of the map grow even if there are less than 1000 values in the map ? I would like to determine the memory usage of a map, or at least determine an upper bound. It is to evaluate the cost in memory usage of a cache.

Comment: @chmike This answer gives you the tools to test it. Have you tried? Btw yes, memory usage and allocation might increase a little due to hashmap internals (buckets usage and allocation). But that's "tiny" compared to the memory footprint of the whole map.

Comment: why is `x` a global variable though? what's the difference from putting it on the stack of `BenchmarkEmptyMap`?

Comment: @SOFe I just made it a package level var to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away (as it's never read).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same requirement, and finally I did it with the help of unsafe, and you can look at [MapSize](https://github.com/520MianXiangDuiXiang520/MapSize), but it's worth noting that it's not entirely accurate.