# String memory usage in Golang

Tags: string, go, memory, size

I was optimizing a code using a **map[string]string** where the value of the map was only either "A" or "B". So I thought Obviously a **map[string]bool** was way better as the map hold around 50 millions elements.

```
var a = "a"
var a2 = "Why This ultra long string take the same amount of space in memory as 'a'"
var b = true
var c map[string]string
var d map[string]bool

c["t"] = "A"
d["t"] = true

fmt.Printf("a: %T, %d\n", a, unsafe.Sizeof(a))
fmt.Printf("a2: %T, %d\n", a2, unsafe.Sizeof(a2))
fmt.Printf("b: %T, %d\n", b, unsafe.Sizeof(b))
fmt.Printf("c: %T, %d\n", c, unsafe.Sizeof(c))
fmt.Printf("d: %T, %d\n", d, unsafe.Sizeof(d))
fmt.Printf("c: %T, %d\n", c, unsafe.Sizeof(c["t"]))
fmt.Printf("d: %T, %d\n", d, unsafe.Sizeof(d["t"]))
```

And the result was:

```
a: string, 8
a2: string, 8
b: bool, 1
c: map[string]string, 4
d: map[string]bool, 4
c2: map[string]string, 8
d2: map[string]bool, 1
```

While testing I found something weird, why **a2** with a really long string use 8 bytes, same as **a** which has only one letter?

Comment: use go's  profiler to optimize program.

Comment: General and helpful rule: Always read the official documentation of each function and each package carefully. The answer is there.

Comment: For those wondering like I did: the OP is using 32bit Go. It is 16 bytes on playground.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`unsafe.Sizeof()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) does not recursively go into data structures, it just reports the "shallow" size of the value passed. Quoting from its doc:

> **The size does not include any memory possibly referenced by x.** For instance, if x is a slice, Sizeof returns the size of the slice descriptor, not the size of the memory referenced by the slice.

Maps in Go are implemented as pointers, so `unsafe.Sizeof(somemap)` will report the size of that pointer.

Strings in Go are just headers containing a pointer and a length. See [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader):

```
type StringHeader struct {
        Data uintptr
        Len  int
}
```

So `unsafe.Sizeof(somestring)` will report the size of the above struct, which is independent of the length of the `string` value (which is the value of the `Len` field).

To get the actual memory requirement of a map ("deeply"), see [How much memory do golang maps reserve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278003/how-much-memory-do-golang-maps-reserve/46278240#46278240) and also [How to get memory size of variable in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-memory-size-of-variable-in-golang/44258164#44258164)

Go stores the UTF-8 encoded byte sequences of `string` values in memory. The builtin function [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) reports the byte-length of a `string`, so
basically the memory required to store a `string` value in memory is:

```
var str string = "some string"

stringSize := len(str) + int(unsafe.Sizeof(str))
```

Also don't forget that a `string` value may be constructed by slicing another, bigger string, and thus even if the original string is no longer referenced (and thus no longer needed), the bigger backing array will still be required to be kept in memory for the smaller string slice.

For example:

```
s := "some loooooooong string"
s2 := s[:2]
```

Here, even though memory requirement for `s2` would be `len(s2) + unsafe.Sizeof(str) = 2 + unsafe.Sizeof(str)`, still, the whole backing array of `s` will be retained.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So basicaly following the StringHeader struct, the size of a string in memory is equal to sizeof(uintptr) * Len ?

Comment: @Dylan No, `StringHeader.Data` is a pointer where the bytes (characters) of the string are stored in memory. The size of a `string` value is basically its length (it's a byte-length), plus the size of the header. See edited answer.

Comment: I get an error when trying to run the example https://play.golang.org/p/ugZoV5PeE9H

Comment: @sprut Thanks for the note, I fixed it (it just needs an `int` conversion).

Comment: @sprut here is your example corrected https://play.golang.org/p/PyX257Efll1