# How to monitor golang websocket server for memory leaks

Tags: go, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Right now I am pretty much doing this:

```
    import (
      "unsafe"
    )
    
    func (s *Service)  logStats(){
      go func(){
    
        for {
    
           time.Sleep(50*time.Second);
    

           vbl.Stdout.Debug(
                vbl.Id("f30bb768-280a-4bbf-9c17-2b7214e91c69"),
                fmt.Sprintf("topicIdToRMQChannels:%v/%v,", len(s.topicIdToRMQChannels), unsafe.Sizeof(s.topicIdToRMQChannels)),
                fmt.Sprintf("conversationIdToConns:%v/%v,", len(s.conversationIdToConns), unsafe.Sizeof(s.conversationIdToConns)),
                fmt.Sprintf("clientIdToConns:%v/%v,", len(s.clientIdToConns), unsafe.Sizeof(s.clientIdToConns)),
                fmt.Sprintf("userIdToConvId:%v/%v,", len(s.userIdToConvId), unsafe.Sizeof(s.userIdToConvId)),
                fmt.Sprintf("convIdToUserIds:%v/%v", len(s.convIdToUserIds), unsafe.Sizeof(s.convIdToUserIds)),
                fmt.Sprintf("redisMap:%v/%v,", len(s.redisMap.IdMap), unsafe.Sizeof(s.redisMap.IdMap)),
                fmt.Sprintf("rabbitMap:%v/%v,", len(s.rabbitMap.IdMap), unsafe.Sizeof(s.rabbitMap.IdMap)),
                fmt.Sprintf("kafkaMap:%v/%v", len(s.kafkaMap.IdMap), unsafe.Sizeof(s.kafkaMap.IdMap)),
            )
    
        }
    
    }()
  }
```

The above is logging pretty much all the data structures that could accidentally grow too large during lifetime of server.

Is there a better way to monitor memory usage? The `unsafe.Sizof()` call always seems to return 8.

Comment: `unsafe.SizeOf` tells you the size of the value you pass in, -- a 64bit pointer is 8 bytes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851788/string-memory-usage-in-golang/52851967#52851967, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-total-referenced-memory-of-a-variable

Comment: yes unsafe.SizeOf is worthless

Comment: `unsafe.Sizeof` is useful for exactly what it was designed to do (which is typically for low-level allocation, pointer manipulation, etc). Even if you are going to add up all the values in slices and maps, you need to know the size of the actual values to add up, for which would can use `unsafe.Sizeof`.

Comment: And they would all be 8 wouldn't they so .. it's just a linear operator that can be ignored

Comment: Those pointers obviously point to values, which may be of various different sizes

Comment: no Jim it seems to always return the size of the address, it doesn't seem to read "size of values"

Comment: You need to deference a pointer to get the value to which it points, this is how pointers work. A pointer is also a value, and `unsafe.Sizeof` is just returning the size of the value you gave it.

Comment: Try it on a value vs pointer Jim and let me know what you find

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/cukJU848w1j. See what a pointer is in the [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/1)

Comment: I keep getting 8 no matter how many times I deref/ref a pointer. I see the playground and I understand pointers - Try a map instance big man, lmk what you see with a map

Comment: A map is implanted as a pointer, you can’t directly deference that. The size of the map struct needs to be referenced from the implementation if you actually need it, but it’s mostly the values stored in the map where you begin adding things up.

Comment: @JimB the answer I have a is pretty good way to find the size of a map in terms of tracking down bugs related to memory leaks. Are you telling me there is no native (core) way of determining a size of a map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256576/discussion-between-jimb-and-alexander-mills).

Answer (score -2):

Basically unsafe.SizeOf is worthless, so you have to calculate the size according to your own design, this is how I did it:

```
func calculateGenericMapSize[T comparable, K any](m map[T]K) []int {
    // calculate size (memory) of map
    totalKeyLength := len(m)
    totalValueLength := 0

    for _, v := range m {

        val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

        // If v is a pointer, find the value it points to
        if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && !val.IsNil() {
            val = val.Elem()
        }

        switch val.Kind() {
        case reflect.Map, reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
            totalValueLength += val.Len()
        default:
            totalValueLength += 1
        }
    }

    return []int{totalKeyLength, totalValueLength}
}

func calculateMapSize[T comparable, K comparable, Z any](m map[T]map[K]Z) []int {
    totalKeyLength := len(m)
    totalValueLength := 0

    for _, innerMap := range m {
        totalValueLength += len(innerMap)
    }

    return []int{totalKeyLength, totalValueLength}
}

func (s *Service) logMemoryStats() {

    go func() {


            vbl.Stdout.Debug(
                vbl.Id("f30bb768-280a-4bbf-9c17-2b7214e91c69"),
                fmt.Sprintf("topicIdToRMQChannels:%v", calculateMapSize(s.topicIdToRMQChannels)),
                fmt.Sprintf("conversationIdToConns:%v,", calculateMapSize(s.conversationIdToConns)),
                fmt.Sprintf("clientIdToConns:%v,", calculateMapSize(s.clientIdToConns)),
                fmt.Sprintf("userIdToConvId:%v,", calculateMapSize(s.userIdToConvId)),
                fmt.Sprintf("convIdToUserIds:%v", calculateMapSize(s.convIdToUserIds)),
                fmt.Sprintf("redisMap:%v,", calculateGenericMapSize(s.redisMap.IdMap)),
                fmt.Sprintf("rabbitMap:%v,", calculateGenericMapSize(s.rabbitMap.IdMap)),
                fmt.Sprintf("kafkaMap:%v", calculateGenericMapSize(s.kafkaMap.IdMap)),
            )


    }()

}
```