# Golang How to extract the sizeof struct to int

Tags: go, int, sizeof

I'm starting to learn golang but come across what I hope is a simple problem.

I have a file written to in C with several structs. ie myStruct's
Now I  want to read one struct of data from this file.

In C I simple open a file and move the fileptr number of structs * sizeofStruct. Like this

```
int sizeofStruct = sizeof(myStruct)
seek(filehandle, searchNo*sizeofStruct)
read(filehandle, &data, sizeofStruct)
```

This doesn't seem to be as simple in Golang as "sizeof"... rather multiple conversions ending up in uintptr... something, or reflect.int32()

```
var spect Spectrum // struct Spectrum
const SizeOfSpectrum = unsafe.Sizeof(spect)
```

I was hoping  SizeOfSpectrum would contain equal to `sizeof(spect)` in C

Can you guys help me to get the size of a struct in an int variable?

Comment: See possible duplicate of [How to get memory size of variable in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-memory-size-of-variable-in-golang/44258164#44258164)

Comment: Binary data is usually read with the [encoding/binary package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) in Go. If that is an option you don't have to deal with struct sizes; the package handles that automatically.

Comment: How is the `Spectrum` Go `struct` defined?

Comment: @peterSO, the struct is taken from the C-definition straight and first defined as type INT int16, type CHAR byte. Then made the Spectrum struct like this
    type Spectrums struct {
     // char  verkid[30];
     verkID [30]CHAR
     // int  streamnr
     streamNr INT
     // int  cellinfo; 
     cellInfo INT
     .... a.s.o.
    }

Comment: @icza thanks, They speak of traversing through the struct first and returning the size of the actual values, ? meaning the values from file or empty struct??
Or do I miss something here?...
I'll give it a try to see

Comment: @Peter Yes that is true, however I want to read one specific struct from the file at specific position ie noOfStruct * datasize and extract the data

Comment: The only issue left with this, after testing, unsafe.Sizeof(struct) give me the correct size as a uintptr. I canprint the value with like fmt.Print(unsafe.Sizeof(struct)) but I haven't found a way to get the numeric value and multiply with another, say int16 value. Purpose is to seek a position within the file and use ReadAt(receiverAsByteArray, intFromWhatPosition)
Or later on, to write struct on same position

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file written to in C with several structs. ie myStruct's Now
>   I want to read one struct of data from this file. In C i simple open a
>   file and move the fileptr number of structs * sizeofStruct.
>
> I haven't found a way to get the numeric value and multiply with
>   another, say int16 value. Purpose is to seek a position within the
>   file.

---

You do the same thing in Go, using explicit conversions.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    type S struct{ F int32 }
    i16 := int16(42)
    // The Go Programming Language Specification
    // https://golang.org/ref/spec
    // Numeric types
    // Explicit conversions are required when different
    // numeric types are mixed in an expression or assignment.
    // func (f *File) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)
    offset := int64(i16) * int64(unsafe.Sizeof(S{}))
    fmt.Println(offset)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/YFyU11Lf2qc

Output:

```
168
```