# Is there a way to compute sizeof a type in golang?

Tags: go

https://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample/public/memory-and-sizeof.html

It shows how to compute the sizeof of a variable. But I want to compute the sizeof of a type (e.g., 'uint32'). Is there a way to do so in Go.

Comment: No. The `reflect` can do inspection of types, but must start with a concrete value. Typically, if a framework wants to work off  of a certain type, callers register with a zero-value of the type e.g. [gob.Register](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Register).

Comment: This may solve.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-memory-size-of-variable-in-go

Comment: Can you tell us what want you do that for? I'm asking because Go has specific reason to have `Sizeof` in the `unsafe` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Type.Size](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Size) to get the size of a type.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*uint32)(nil)).Elem()
fmt.Println(t.Size())  // prints 4
```

The expression `reflect.TypeOf((*X)(nil)).Elem()` gets the [reflect.Type](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type) for any type `X`.

In the case of uint32 and other numeric types, the simpler expression `reflect.TypeOf(uint32(0))` can be used to get the type.

The [unsafe.Sizeof](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Sizeof) function also works, but it requires a value of the type.

```
fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(uint32(0)))  // prints 4
```

Comment: Technically this is still evaluating a value of the type.

Comment: @colm.anseo The expression `reflect.TypeOf((*someType)(nil)).Elem()` does **not** evaluate a value of `someType`.  It does evaluate a `*someType`.

Comment: It's a pointer of the `someType`. Memory pointers take up space. The fact that it is `nil` does not change the fact that it is a value (taking up 8 bytes).

Comment: @colm.anseo  The purpose of using `reflect.TypeOf((*X)(nil)).Elem()` is for syntax.  The syntax works for any type `X`.  The syntax also avoids allocating an arbitrarily large value on the stack.

Comment: I'm not faulting your method. My understanding from the OP question was is there a language construct to determine a type's footprint without using a *value* - and in Go this is not possible.

Comment: Oh, I thought OP was asking how to get the size without creating a variable.

Comment: This trades allocating 4 bytes in the stack (which is essentially free), for allocating multiple reflect type implementations, each of which are at least 56 bytes? You're not going to find many instances of types that a zero value will make any impact on your stack allocation, which starts at 2k.

Comment: (it would be easier to provide feedback if you didn't make a make a new account every other day, e.g. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13214722/thwd), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13718126/thwd), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532430/thwd), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13716866/thwd), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13667087/thwd), [six](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13724128/thwd), [seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13735910/thwd), [eight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13745130/thwd)???)

Comment: @BlahBlahBlah: Ah yes, it looks like `rtype` ends up bring a pointer to the runtime `_type`. Either way, `unsafe.Sizeof` will likely be much faster, and definitely clearer in 99%of use cases.