# Why is bool type in Go 16 bytes long?

Tags: go, boolean, size

I am going through the "A Tour of Go" tutorial and I modified one of the examples a bit to find that the size of bool in Go is 16 bytes?!
Am I not using the correct function to calculate this or is it really that the size of bool is 16 bytes?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v*2)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v))
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T, but it's length is: %v bytes!\n", v, unsafe.Sizeof(v))
    }
}

func main() {
    do(21)
    do("hello")
    do(false)
}
```

Output:

```
Twice 21 is 42
"hello" is 5 bytes long
I don't know about type bool, but it's length is: 16 bytes!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That 16 bytes is the size of the `interface{}` type. `v` is of type `interface{}` which is implemented something like a pair of 2 pointers (one to the dynamic type descriptor and one to the dynamic value). You can learn more about interface "internals" here: [Russ Cox: Go Data Structures: Interfaces](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

This is because in the `default` branch there is no "extracted" type, in the `default` branch type of `v` is identical to the type of `i`.

If you add this:

```
b := false
fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T, but it's length is: %v bytes!\n",
    b, unsafe.Sizeof(b))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eQUdCDUQjG4)):

```
I don't know about type bool, but it's length is: 1 bytes!
```

So the size of the `bool` type is 1 byte.

Also beware when you use `unsafe.Sizeof()` for composite types (strings, slices included), it does not include memory referred to by elements. For details see [How to get memory size of variable in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-memory-size-of-variable-in-go/44258164#44258164)

Comment: Wait..I thought "i" is of type interface{} and "v" is the extracted value out of it, isn't that right?

Comment: @Vallerious Yes, that's right, but in the `default` branch it is of type `interface{}` (more specifically it's the same as the type of `i`).

Comment: Every value in Go has a specific type defined at compile time. `v` cannot be "whatever type the value of `i` really is", it has to be a well-defined type; in this case, `interface{}`.