# How much memory is allocated to map keys? ie will map[uint16]uint16 be 2 bytes per key or stored as uint32/64 regardless?

Tags: dictionary, go, memory

I'm wondering if uint8 or uint16 Go map keys will be stored as 1/2 bytes or they will have uint32/64 memory allocations regardless of specifying something smaller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maps are hashmaps in Go, their internals is non-trivial. Common sense tells the key size should make a difference, but since this is not in the language specification, measure it yourself.

Check [How to get memory size of variable in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-memory-size-of-variable-in-go/44258164#44258164) for how to measure size of arbitrary variables.

For example create a test:

```
const size = 250

func getMap8(size int) map[uint8]uint16 {
    m := make(map[uint8]uint16, size)
    for i := uint8(0); i < uint8(size); i++ {
        m[i] = uint16(i)
    }
    return m
}

func getMap16(size int) map[uint16]uint16 {
    m := make(map[uint16]uint16, size)
    for i := uint16(0); i < uint16(size); i++ {
        m[i] = i
    }
    return m
}

func getMap32(size int) map[uint32]uint16 {
    m := make(map[uint32]uint16, size)
    for i := uint32(0); i < uint32(size); i++ {
        m[i] = uint16(i)
    }
    return m
}

func getMap64(size int) map[uint64]uint16 {
    m := make(map[uint64]uint16, size)
    for i := uint64(0); i < uint64(size); i++ {
        m[i] = uint16(i)
    }
    return m
}

func Benchmark8(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        getMap8(size)
    }
}

func Benchmark16(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        getMap16(size)
    }
}

func Benchmark32(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        getMap32(size)
    }
}

func Benchmark64(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        getMap64(size)
    }
}
```

Running it with `go test -bench . -benchmem`, the output is:

```
Benchmark8-8      95862    11210 ns/op   3188 B/op       4 allocs/op
Benchmark16-8    107731    11017 ns/op   3572 B/op       4 allocs/op
Benchmark32-8    150126     8496 ns/op   4980 B/op       4 allocs/op
Benchmark64-8    144655     8959 ns/op   6644 B/op       4 allocs/op
```

So the map size is indeed smaller if the key size is smaller, but obviously the key and value size together determine the final size.

Size of a map of type `map[uint8]uint16` with 250 entries is about 3188 bytes, a map with `uint16` key type is 3572 bytes, a map with `uint32` key type is 4980 bytes, and a map with `uint64` key type is 6644 bytes.