# How to get memory bytes from map or array in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go

If we use a map like `map[string]string`

Is it possible to get an actual memory use of said map from the code below?

```
for i, v := range x.(map[string]string) {

  CacheBytes += len([]byte(i))
  CacheBytes += len([]byte(v))

}
```

When trying to get memory bytes from any variable type, I wrote this:

```
// get bytes from different types

        switch x.(type) {

        // string would be simple
        case string:
            s = x.(string)
            CacheBytes += len([]byte(s))

        // but in case of map...?
        case map[string]string:

            for i, v := range x.(map[string]string) {

                CacheBytes += len([]byte(i))
                CacheBytes += len([]byte(v))

            }

        // Or array...????
        case []string:
```

How can we get the actual number of bytes of memory that are used by a map or an array in Golang?

I know it's a bit complicated coz' of data structure, would be appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847549/golang-computing-the-memory-footprint-or-byte-length-of-a-map

Comment: The expression `len(s)` returns the same value as `len([]byte(s))`.  The former is simpler and more efficient. Also, use `switch x := x.(type) {` to eliminate need for type assertions in the case statements.

Comment: default map size + (len(map) * 8) + (len(map) * 8 * sizeof(key)) + (len(map) * 8 * sizeof(val)) ???